# folder creation problem during thumbnail generation c#

Tags: c#

I am generating Thumbnails, Everything goes fine and smooth but there is a problem during the creation of sub folder. Suppose:

**C:\Users\a\Desktop\b test\Iceland\Haskolinn2**
the destination thumbnail folder will look like this:
**C:\Users\a\Desktop\a test\Iceland**
**C:\Users\a\Desktop\a test\Haskolinn2**

it must look like 
**C:\Users\a\Desktop\a test\Iceland\Haskolinn2**

here is the code:

```
 public void CreateThumbnail(double wid, double hght, bool Isprint)
    {


        string saveAt = "C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\a test";

string b= "C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\b test\\iceland"         
string [] bb = Directory.GetDirectories(b, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

       foreach (string path in bb)
      {
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            string outputPath = Path.Combine(saveAt, directory.Name);
            foreach (FileInfo f in directory.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {



                if (f.DirectoryName != directory.FullName)
                {
                    outputPath = Path.Combine(saveAt, directory.Name);

                }
                if (!Directory.Exists(outputPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath);

                }


                using (Image imagesize = Image.FromFile(f.FullName))

                using (Bitmap bitmapNew = new Bitmap(imagesize))
                {
                    double maxWidth = wid;
                    double maxHeight = hght;
                    int w = imagesize.Width;

                    int h = imagesize.Height;
                    // Longest and shortest dimension 
                    int longestDimension = (w > h) ? w : h;

                    int shortestDimension = (w < h) ? w : h;
                    // propotionality  
                    float factor = ((float)longestDimension) / shortestDimension;

                    // default width is greater than height    
                    double newWidth = maxWidth;
                    double newHeight = maxWidth / factor;

                    // if height greater than width recalculate  
                    if (w < h)
                    {
                        newWidth = maxHeight / factor;

                        newHeight = maxHeight;
                    }

                    string fileName = Path.Combine(outputPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name) + ".jpeg");

                    bitmapNew.GetThumbnailImage((int)newWidth, (int)newHeight, () => false, IntPtr.Zero)

                        .Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);



                }

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: And what is the problem (also any error messages might help) ?

Comment: @SWeko No there is no error, but on physical file system, the structure of directories is not in the same as the original one. the subfolder are not created as sub-folder but are created as parent folder. Suppose Folder A contain two sub folders (B,C), so in destination it will be like (A,B,C) which is wrong.

Comment: What's the folder structure in `jak`? And you haven't used `b` in the above sample.

Comment: @conqenator i forgot to update the question, now the jak is replaced by b.

Comment: @conqenator  I have updated the code, you can see the class how it work. and can suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, I guess the `Path.Combine` call is not doing what you think it should.

When given two fully qualified paths, [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) basically ignores the first, and returns the second. Example:

```
string path1 = @"C:\Test\Path\"
string path2 = @"C:\Other\Path\"
Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(path1, path2)); //prints C:\Other\Path
```

In your code this means that you are not using the destination folder for the thumbnails, but the source folder. You could try stripping the full path down to a folder name, like

```
string path1 = @"C:\Test\Path\"
string path2 = @"C:\Other\FolderToCombine\"
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path2);

Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(path1, di.Name)); //prints C:\Test\Path\FolderToCombine
```

---

After the question edit:
The problem is that for a structure like

```
...A
   |-B
   |-C
```

your `Directory.GetDirectories` call will return strings like "..\A", "..\A\B" "..\A\C".
When those string are used in a `DirectoryInfo` constructor you get directories with names of "A", "B" and "C", so in effect, you are linearizing a tree structure (Things could get really interesting if the B folder had a subfolder called A :))

You could do something like:

```
public void CreateThumbnail(double wid, double hght, bool Isprint)
{
   string saveAt = "C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\a test";  
   string b= "C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\b test\\iceland"
   ProcessFolder(b, saveAt, wid, hght, Isprint);
}

public static void ProcessFolder(string sourceFolder, string destFolder, double wid, double hght, bool Isprint)
{
  //create the dest folder if it does not exist
  Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder); 

  //get info about the source folder
  DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder);

  //get the source files (only in the current source folder)
  foreach (FileInfo f in diSource.GetFiles("*.*"))
  {
    //calculate the destination file name
    string destFileName = Path.Combine(destFolder, f.Name);
    //thumbnail processing here

    //quick test
    File.Copy(f.FullName, destFileName);
  }

  //get all subfolders for the current folder
  foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder, "*.*"))
  {
    //calculate the new output folder for a given subfolder
    // if the source folder is \src\a\, and the dest folder is \dest\
    // this results in \dest\a
    DirectoryInfo diSubfolder = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
    string outputPath = Path.Combine(destFolder, diSubfolder.Name);

    ProcessFolder(dir, outputPath, wid, hght, Isprint); //call recursively
  }
}
```

This example will copy a folder to another location, just replace the File.Copy call with your logic.

Comment: @SWeko so what i need to change in Path.Combine? or should i replace Path.Combine with other function?

Comment: @SWeko I have updated the code, you can see the class how it work. and can suggest me.

Comment: @safi, I see your problem now, and you will need recursion to solve this. Will change the answer to reflect it.

Comment: @SWeko, Thanks, did you change the answer? i am waiting to solve this.

Comment: @Safi, modified, now you should see where the problem is.

Comment: @SWeko i modiefied the changes but however now i do not get any sub-folder. i get all the files from subfolder in one folder. did you skip the foreach statement in FileInfo?

Comment: @Safi, yes, all `SearchOption.AllDirectories` flags should be removed,  this method is working one folder at a time to preserve the structure.

Comment: @SWeko  `using (Image imagesize = Image.FromFile(f.FullName))` then how will i be able to get the file name as i am using `foreach (FileInfo f `

Comment: @Safi, I don't see how that would change, the fileInfos will be the same

Comment: @SWeko can you adjust the changes in the orginial programm? i am confuse to adjust the setting in it:(

Comment: @Safi, I've modified the answer to fit your existing calls, but the important thing is that you should understand what it does and why, not just that it works.

Comment: @SWeko `foreach (FileInfo f in directory.GetFiles("*.*"))` where does it come from? i understand the logic, the thing is everything goes okay in my mind but cant adjust it in the program. i get error at this and when i sepcify disourse insetead of directory, then it get only one folder not the sub-folder, thanks alot in deed for your help.

Comment: I've reworked the Process method a bit, take a loot at it now. BTW, works on my machine :)

Comment: @SWeko I am wondering how it is working because on my machine it is not working, i do not know what is wrong,can you kindly put all the program here so i can follow it step by step. :) sorry for asking this but i have to :)

Comment: @safi, this is the exact program I used (only with different paths, of course). Try to debug it step by step, and see where it differs from your expectations.

Comment: @Safi, GDI is the drawing component, so I guess, the thumbnail code needs reviewing :)

Comment: @SWeko, due to this reason i follow the my earlier soltion which i posted in the question, and that one did not gives that GDI error,i couldnt fix this GDI+ :(

Comment: @SWeko `string fileName = Path.Combine(outputPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name) + ".Jpeg");` the erroe happens at this point,,